# Calling javascript externally not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, external

I am trying to load this javascript externally, but it seems to not be working? Is there a reason for this?

I have been reading around, and I am loading jquery first before everything. But when calling out to these functions they will not load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //add span to numbers
  var elem = document.getElementById('passage');
  elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(/\b(\d+)\b/g, '<span>$1</span>');

  //menu toggle     
  $("#social-wrap li:nth-child(6)").click(function () {
    $("#phone-nav").slideToggle("slow");
  });

  //nav slideDown      
  $('#main-nav li').hover(function () {
    //show its submenu
    $('ul', this).slideDown(100);
  }, function () {
    //hide its submenu
    $('ul', this).slideUp(100);
  });

  //show/hide countdown  
  $('#show').click(function () {
    $('#countdown').slideDown('slow');
    return false;
  });

  $('#hide').click(function () {
    $('#countdown').slideUp('fast');
    return false;
  });

  $('#hide,#show').click(function () {
    $('#hide,#show').toggle();
  })

});
```

*EDIT*

Here is the link to the wordpress theme I am building: http://beta.revival.tv/ 
As well as the JS file: http://beta.revival.tv/wp-content/themes/revival-theme/lib/scripts/main.js?ver=1.1 
Sorry for how messy the site is, still working on it.

Comment: How're you linking to the external file?

Comment: Calling out to *what* two functions? Calling from where?

Comment: And why are you using stuff like `document.getElementById`, when you have jquery..

Comment: Syntactically, your code appears fine. The problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: I'm fairly new with using JavaScript. Way better in HTML/CSS. I'm building a Wordpress theme and calling the JavaScript file from a JS folder in the themes folder.

Comment: @MichielvanVaardegem here is the js I'm calling: http://beta.revival.tv/wp-content/themes/revival-theme/lib/scripts/main.js?ver=1.1 as well as the actual site: http://beta.revival.tv/ sorry the site is a mess right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, I have heard that Wordpress messes with the $ shorthand for JQuery. You may be able to wrap your code in something like this in order to be able to use the $ shorthand. Otherwise try using the full jQuery() instead of $().

```
( function( $ ) {
   // allows you to use $ inside of this wrapper.

} )( jQuery );
```

Also, how are you adding jQuery to your theme?

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-you-get-jquery-to-work-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#hide,#show').click(function () {
    $('#hide,#show').toggle();
})
```

here semicolon is missing.

Try it now again. Hope it works. Even if it doesn't ,post your main html page where
   you are calling it.

Comment: Missing semicolon would never execute javascript code as far as I believe.

Comment: There's something like automatic semicolon insertion in JavaScript.

Comment: Type in your console: function foo(){alert("bar")};foo(), works

Comment: Ok.But when I tried using external javascript code to a perl.My javascript didn't get executed.And I went looking for,I found semicolon missing.After correcting it,it did.That's why I thought it could be the reason.Anyways,there might be something else.I will look into it.Thanx !

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm away from my computer right now. I will try out your suggestions when I get back.

Answer (score 0):

one really strange thing about including an external script is that it matters how you close it.
This:

```
<script type='blah' src='path'></script>
```

works, and this:

```
<script type='blah' src='path' />
```

Doesn't.
I don't know why, I only know this could happen.

Comment: aargh, my code is disappearing! Could someone please format? My code is there, but only visible on the edit page!

Comment: your code has to be separated from regular text by a blank line.